# 48 hrs reminder for last phases of mod-election?

Tags: support, moderators, election

There was a nice banner for 48 hours at the start (nomination) phase of the present [moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election). My question is if this reminder will pop up again when the election reaches the other two phases (`primary` and `election`)?

I ask because there's a reasonable chance I forget all about it and miss the chance to vote (and with me, probably more members).

Comment: Hmmm, good question! `:P`

Comment: I would hope and indeed expect that there will be more system messages about the election.

Comment: @ChrisF I would hope that if people are really concerned about who the next mods are, they could manage to remember to vote, but I know that's foolishly optimistic of me

Comment: @Michael, not all people are good at remembering stuff (me included). This has nothing to do with the fact I am not concerned with the election. And my overuse of alcohol has nothing to do with this. :)

Comment: I'm terrible at remembering self, but that's what calendars and reminders are for. Anyway, I suspect like ChrisF said there will be more system messages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will be a banner for 48 hours at the start of the nomination and primary phases.  At the start of the election phase there will be a banner and a private message delivered to all eligible voters.

Comment: +1 on the private message.